# Error message on MTP path when connecting Android phone, but path is OK

Tags: linux-mint, android, mate-desktop, mtp, caja

I am using Linux Mint MATE 21.2. When I plug my Samsung phone (A14) on USB and then tap "Allow" on it, I get the following error box in Caja:

```
Couldn't show "mtp://SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_RX8W8063KMP/".
Error: Object does not exist in path "/org/gtk/vfs/mount/1"
Select another viewer and try again.
```

But after I dismiss the error box I see the phone contents are perfectly accessible. And Ctrl-L shows the path is exactly the one showed in the error message.

Race condition thing?

[image]